# How to remove parent element without deleting its contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to remove a parent without a child? There are 3 parents I need to delete, which is class "`DELETE-A DELETE-B DELETE-C`". Most articles I read, just delete 1 element only

Or maybe can i delete all the contents in the class `DELETE-A` without deleting the contents of the class `KASKUS-C`? So the class `DELETE-D` and class `DELETE-H` classes will also be deleted

```
<div class="KASKUS-A">
    <div class="KASKUS-B">
        <div class="DELETE-A">
            <div class="DELETE-B">
                <div class="DELETE-C">
                    <div class="KASKUS-C">
                        <div><img src="http://www.how-to-draw-funny-cartoons.com/image-files/cartoon-owl-3f.gif" class="visible horizontal"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="DELETE-C">
                    <div class="KASKUS-C">
                        <div><img src="http://www.drawingcoach.com/image-files/cartoon_cow_st6.gif" class="visible horizontal"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="DELETE-D">
            <div class="DELETE-F">prev</div>
            <div class="DELETE-G">next</div>
        </div>
        <div class="DELETE-H">
            <div class="DELETE-I"><span></span></div>
            <div class="DELETE-J"><span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be this

```
<div class="KASKUS-A">
    <div class="KASKUS-B">
        <div class="KASKUS-C">
            <div><img src="http://www.how-to-draw-funny-cartoons.com/image-files/cartoon-owl-3f.gif" class="visible horizontal"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="KASKUS-C">
            <div><img src="http://www.drawingcoach.com/image-files/cartoon_cow_st6.gif" class="visible horizontal"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I using this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.DELETE-D').remove();
      $('.DELETE-H').remove();

      $('.DELETE-A').remove();
      $('.DELETE-B').remove();
      $('.DELETE-C').not("KASKUS-C").remove();

      // and

      $('.DELETE-C:not("KASKUS-C")').remove();

      // and

      var DELETEC = $('.DELETE-C').contents();
      $(".DELETE-C").replaceWith(DELETEC);

      // and

      $('.DELETE-A').not("KASKUS-C").remove();

      // etc 

});
```

But still not working https://jsfiddle.net/wwg35jeu/

Comment: [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) will do. See https://jsfiddle.net/wwg35jeu/1/

Comment: You would need to move the children out of those parents first, otherwise they will get destroyed with the parents when you remove the latter. Simply appending them to their target position before removing the (then empty) parents should work.

Comment: What if only once unwrap? Because I use `$(window).bind("load resize"`. So every window size changes, then `unwrap` will always be active, and remove all elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery `unwrap()` function if your element has children, or `remove()` if it has none :

```js
$('[class*="DELETE-"]').each(function(){
  if($(this).children().first().length > 0) $(this).children().first().unwrap();
  else $(this).remove();
});

console.log($('body').children().eq(1)[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="KASKUS-A">
    <div class="KASKUS-B">
        <div class="DELETE-A">
            <div class="DELETE-B">
                <div class="DELETE-C">
                    <div class="KASKUS-C">
                        <div><img src="http://www.how-to-draw-funny-cartoons.com/image-files/cartoon-owl-3f.gif" class="visible horizontal"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="DELETE-C">
                    <div class="KASKUS-C">
                        <div><img src="http://www.drawingcoach.com/image-files/cartoon_cow_st6.gif" class="visible horizontal"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="DELETE-D">
            <div class="DELETE-F">prev</div>
            <div class="DELETE-G">next</div>
        </div>
        <div class="DELETE-H">
            <div class="DELETE-I"><span></span></div>
            <div class="DELETE-J"><span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```